# set Property method called tens of thousands of times when I use a custom UI view in react native iOS

Tags: react-native

I created a custom UI view under this facebook tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#content

MyCustomView.h

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *test;
@end
```

MyCustomView.m  (init method is omitted)

```
- (void)setTest:(NSString *)test
{
  self.test = test;
}
```

And I expose this property to JS in MyCustomViewManager

MyCustomViewManager.h

```
@interface ReactVideoViewManager : RCTViewManager
@end
```

MyCustomViewManager.m

```
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()
- (UIView *)view
{
  MyCustomView *videoView = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
  return;
}
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(test, BOOL);
```

I used this view in JS as follows:

```
<MyCustomView style={styles.row} test={true}></MyCustomView>
```

However, when the MyCustomView object initialized, the setTest method called tens of thousands of times and crashed at last.
Did anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a working solution might be:

```
- (void)setTest:(NSString *)test
{
  _test = test;
}
```